# Why can't i see this d3 bar chart in an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, svg, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I can see the svg elements in the chrome inspector, but there's nothing on the page. The svg element is visible, but none of the rect elements inside show up.

```
<div class="chart-area">
  <svg width="750" height="263">
    <g transform="translate(0,0)">
      <rect y="0" height="263" width="150"></rect>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(187.5,0)">
      <rect y="263" height="0" width="150"></rect>
    </g>
    <!-- ... -->
  </svg>
</div>
```

I tried adding a namespace and a viewBox to the svg with no luck. What am i missing here?

---

**Edit - Angular**

The svg is ok. If i copy & paste the svg elements outside of the directive it renders correctly. However generating the svg inside the directive `link` function breaks it.

```
<div class="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

The rendered markup is identical tho, so still very lost.

---

**Edit #2 - Namespace**

Based on AmeliaBR's comment, is there a way to explicitly set the namespace? I've tried to put the namespace in markup, but that doesn't help. I was under the impression `html5` didn't need the namespace, but perhaps i'm wrong?

```
<!-- doesnt work -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
```

---

**Edit #3 - Wtf?**

Robert Longson says there's no namespace in html markup, only xhtml, so that can't be it. So the question remains, why does it work when specified in markup, but not work when added via javascript?

---

**Edit #4 - link function**

The angular link function that generates the svg. [Full plunker here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/7dlqNz28HjX3Ho8vvn6m?p=preview)

```
function link (scope, el) {
  // munge scope data

  var width = el.find('.chart').width()
  var height = Math.floor(width / RATIO)
  console.log(width, height)
  // 750 421

  var svg = d3.select(el.find('svg')[0])
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)

  // x, y

  var bar = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('g')
    .attr('transform', function (d) { return 'translate(' + x(d.x) + ',0)' })

  bar.append('rect')
    .attr('y', function (d) { return y(d.y) })
    .attr('height', function (d) { return height - y(d.y) })
    .attr('width', function () { return width / data.length })
    .attr('fill', 'black')
}
```

---

**Edit #5 - I give up**

The isolated Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/7dlqNz28HjX3Ho8vvn6m?p=preview) seems to work, so there's something whack happening with my code (literally copy/pasted). I give up!

Gonna update all dependencies, clear the cache, try on different browsers, etc. Feel free to close this :(

Comment: How are you creating the elements?  The code as you have it is correct, but there may be something else going on.  This type of behavior (DOM inspector looks correct, but SVG isn't displayed) often happens when people try to create SVG elements with JQuery, because they are not created in the SVG namespace.  However, that shouldn't be a problem if you're creating them in d3.

Comment: Also, what CSS are you using?

Comment: Yes, your svg is fine, [I see what I expect to see](http://plnkr.co/edit/H0UpvLK4wcjepY4CXNv3?p=preview).  One black rect...  You'll need to provide a bit more context to your question.

Comment: @AmeliaBR no styling beyond `rect { fill: black; }`, @Mark updated.

Comment: html doesn't have namespaces in markup, only xhtml does.

Comment: @AJcodez, not to sound like a jerk, but why are you piecemealing this question.  Provide us with enough code to actually replicate your problem...  Again, I've tried out of an angular directive and it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/EJYrn8KTkKxojZUlhIk0?p=preview

Comment: To clarify: the namespace issue is only when you create elements using Javascript, you need to use (or use a library that uses) `createElementNS` instead of `createElement`.  As @RobertLongson said, declaring namespaces in markup won't have an effect in HTML 5; the HTML parser switches to the SVG namespace automatically when it reaches a `<svg>` element.  Please include the angular code you're using to create the content.  If you're passing a large block of markup, you need something that will use the HTML5 parser to interpret it as a whole (automatically inferring the SVG namespace).

Comment: @Mark updated! Didn't mean to hold out! Damned if i do, damned if i dont put all the code up :D

Comment: @AmeliaBR i tried with `createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')` and appending and using that svg element, but still doesn't show up.

Comment: Thank you Mark, AmeliaBR, Robert Longson very, very much. Updating package versions fixed everything. What a day.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a stroke and/or fill color defined.

Comment: Tried setting `fill` with d3 and in css with no luck, thank you tho.

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle is invisible because its height is zero. Set the height-attribute to some value above 0;

Comment: @cirtrus is right that neither `rect` is fully defined. They all need x, y, height and width defined, and nonzero height and width.

Comment: x, y default to 0 if not defined.

Comment: the second rectangle y-position is 263, so the top of the rectangle begins at the bottom end of the viewport.